# How to place Jquery Validate error messages in before radio button option

Tags: jquery-mobile, radio-button, jquery-validate

I am developing an online survey form, and im using jquery mobile, i used the jquery validate plugin.

The problem is,the jquery validate error messages appear after the first radio button option.

How can I place the error message right before the first radio button option.

I tried using this code but seemingly it is not working.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.is(":radio")) {
       error.appendTo(element.parent());
    } else {
       error.insertBefore(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer,

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
if (element.is(":radio")) {
error.prependTo(element.parent());
} else { // This is the default behavior of the script for all fields
error.insertAfter(element);
}
}
```

reference: [Answer to the question I had](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/validate-a-suggestion-for-radio-buttons-the-error-message-placement)